# Floating placement of figure in minipage

Tags: graphics, floats, minipage

Is there a way to place a figure automatically within a minipage. The figure should have the `textwidth` of the minipage.

My first experiments with

```
\begin{minipage}[0mm]{\boxwidthtotal}%
Some text which, I hope, will 'float around' the figure included below. Of course the text must be long enough such that the first part of it appears before and the rest of it below the image.
\begin{figure}[h]%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}%
\end{figure}%
\clearpage%
\end{minipage}%
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, can you show a "manual" code example of what you want to do automatically?

Comment: Please see my edits. As I mentioned, it does not work for me. Basically, I want a minibox which contains some text and an image. If the text is long enough I neither want the image to appear on top nor below the text, but somewhere in-between. Since the text can change, I cannot split it manually.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't think I can help. For those that are smarter than me though, perhaps you could clarify what "long enough" is. More than one line?

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand, and the example does not help, please always make examples _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem, (you can use `example-image` as an image name, most distributions have that). In your example, if the text is 5 lines long, how many lines are supposed to come before the figure and how many after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure but do you mean like this? It hasn't got any relation to latex floats really but puts the image in the middle of the supplied text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi: Some text to fill up space. }
\def\b{\a\a Different text \a\a\a}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xminipage}[2]
{\setbox4\hbox{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\bgroup\hsize=#1\relax\@parboxrestore}
{\par\egroup\egroup
\leavevmode
\vbox{%
\setbox2=\vsplit0 to .5\ht0
\unvbox2
\smallskip
\box4
\smallskip
\unvbox0
}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{xminipage}{100pt}{example-image}
\b
\end{xminipage}}
\quad
\fbox{\begin{xminipage}{8cm}{example-image}
\b
\end{xminipage}}

\fbox{\begin{xminipage}{100pt}{example-image}
\b\b
\end{xminipage}}
\quad
\fbox{\begin{xminipage}{8cm}{example-image}
\b\b
\end{xminipage}}





\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks pretty much like what I am searching.  I will try it asap.

Comment: Works great. Just for my understanding: Why is `\makealetter` needed?

Comment: @highsciguy if `@` has its normal punctuation meaning then `\@parboxrestore`  will run the command `\@` then typeset `parboxrestore`